# Generated Greek letters in plots using the tikzDevice package

Tags: r, greek, rstudio, tikzdevice

With the code below I create in Rstudio the file `gamma0plot.tex`. Then in TexNicCenter in the `figure` environment with the `input` command I load the file `gamma0plot.tex` and generate a .pdf file. In This .pdf,  the title of the x-axis is `g1`, how keep the letter greek `$\gamma_{1}$` while generating the file `gamma0plot.tex` instead of `g1`? Any other suggestions for improving these graphics will be welcome!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
require(tikzDevice)
# make sure the working directory is where you want your tikz file to go
setwd("D:/Área de Trabalho/teste")
# export plot as a .tex file in the tikz format
tikz('gamma0plot.tex', width = 6,height = 3,pointsize = 12) #define plot name size and font size

grid.newpage()

set.seed(000)
m11 <- matrix(rnorm(1000,0,1),1000,1)
df11 <- data.frame(m11)
names(df11) <- c("X")

library(ggplot2)

g1 <- ggplot(df11, aes(x=X))+coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,0.6)) +
  ggtitle("n=500")+ 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(b = 2),size = 6,hjust = 0))
g1 <- g1+geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),      # Histogram with density instead of count on y-axis
                        binwidth=.5,
                        colour="black", fill="white",breaks=seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1)) 
g1 <- g1 + stat_function(fun=dnorm,
                         color="black",geom="area", fill="gray", alpha=0.1,
                         args=list(mean=mean(df11$X), 
                                   sd=sd(df11$X)))
g1 <- g1+  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0, linetype="Valor Verdadeiro"),show.legend =TRUE)
g1 <- g1+  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(df11$X, na.rm=T),    linetype="Valor Estimado"),show.legend =TRUE)
g1 <- g1+  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dotdash","solid")) # Overlay with transparent density plot
g1 <- g1+  xlab(expression(paste(gamma[1])))+ylab("")
g1 <- g1+  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5), units="line"),
                 legend.text=element_text(size=6),
                 legend.position = c(0, 0.97),
                 legend.justification = c("left", "top"),
                 legend.box.just = "left",
                 legend.margin = margin(0,0,0,0),
                 legend.title=element_blank(),
                 legend.direction = "vertical",
                 legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA,fill="transparent", size=.5, linetype="dotted"),
                 legend.key = element_rect(colour = "transparent", fill = NA))
g1 <- g1+ guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 0.5)))


# Adjust key height and width
g1 = g1 + theme(
  legend.key.height = unit(.3, "cm"),
  legend.key.width = unit(0.5, "cm"))

# Get the ggplot Grob
gt1 = ggplotGrob(g1)

# grid.ls(grid.force(gt))  # To get a list of editable grobs

# Edit the relevant keys
library(grid)
gt1 <- editGrob(grid.force(gt1), gPath("key-[3,4]-1-[1,2]"), 
               grep = TRUE, global = TRUE,
               x0 = unit(0, "npc"), y0 = unit(0.5, "npc"), 
               x1 = unit(1, "npc"), y1 = unit(0.5, "npc")) 

###############################################

m12 <- matrix(rnorm(2000,0,1),2000,1)
df12 <- data.frame(m12)
names(df12) <- c("X")
library(ggplot2)

g2 <- ggplot(df12, aes(x=X)) +coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,0.6))+
  ggtitle("n=1000")+ 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(b = 2),size = 6,hjust = 0))
g2 <- g2+geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),      # Histogram with density instead of count on y-axis
                        binwidth=.5,
                        colour="black", fill="white",breaks=seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1)) 
g2 <- g2 + stat_function(fun=dnorm,
                         color="black",geom="area", fill="gray", alpha=0.1,
                         args=list(mean=mean(df12$X), 
                                   sd=sd(df12$X)))
g2 <- g2+  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0, linetype="Valor Verdadeiro"),show.legend =TRUE)
g2 <- g2+  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(df12$X, na.rm=T),    linetype="Valor Estimado"),show.legend =TRUE)
g2 <- g2+  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dotdash","solid")) # Overlay with transparent density plot
g2 <- g2+  xlab(expression(paste(gamma[1])))+ylab("")
g2 <- g2+  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5), units="line"),
                 legend.text=element_text(size=6),
                 legend.position = c(0, 0.97),
                 legend.justification = c("left", "top"),
                 legend.box.just = "left",
                 legend.margin = margin(0,0,0,0),
                 legend.title=element_blank(),
                 legend.direction = "vertical",
                 legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA,fill="transparent", size=.5, linetype="dotted"),
                 legend.key = element_rect(colour = "transparent", fill = NA)) 
g2 <- g2+ guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 0.5)))


 # Adjust key height and width
 g2 = g2 + theme(
   legend.key.height = unit(.3, "cm"),
   legend.key.width = unit(0.5, "cm"))

 # Get the ggplot Grob
 gt2 = ggplotGrob(g2)

# # grid.ls(grid.force(gt))  # To get a list of editable grobs
# 
 # Edit the relevant keys
 library(grid)
 gt2 <- editGrob(grid.force(gt2), gPath("key-[3,4]-1-[1,2]"), 
                 grep = TRUE, global = TRUE,
                 x0 = unit(0, "npc"), y0 = unit(0.5, "npc"), 
                 x1 = unit(1, "npc"), y1 = unit(0.5, "npc")) 

####################################

m13 <- matrix(rnorm(3000,0,1),3000,1)
df13 <- data.frame(m13)
names(df13) <- c("X")
library(ggplot2)

g3 <- ggplot(df13, aes(x=X)) +coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,0.6)) +
  ggtitle("n=2000")+ 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(b = 2),size = 6,hjust = 0))
g3 <- g3+geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),      # Histogram with density instead of count on y-axis
                        binwidth=.5,
                        colour="black", fill="white",breaks=seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1)) 
g3 <- g3 + stat_function(fun=dnorm,
                         color="black",geom="area", fill="gray", alpha=0.1,
                         args=list(mean=mean(df13$X), 
                                   sd=sd(df13$X)))
g3 <- g3+  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0, linetype="Valor Verdadeiro"),show.legend =TRUE)
g3 <- g3+  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(df13$X, na.rm=T),    linetype="Valor Estimado"),show.legend =TRUE)
g3 <- g3+  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dotdash","solid")) # Overlay with transparent density plot
g3 <- g3+  xlab(expression(paste(gamma[1])))+ylab("")
g3 <- g3+  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5), units="line"),
                 legend.text=element_text(size=6),
                 legend.position = c(0, 0.97),
                 legend.justification = c("left", "top"),
                 legend.box.just = "left",
                 legend.margin = margin(0,0,0,0),
                 legend.title=element_blank(),
                 legend.direction = "vertical",
                 legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA,fill="transparent", size=.5, linetype="dotted"),
                 legend.key = element_rect(colour = "transparent", fill = NA))
 g3 <- g3+ guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 0.5)))
# 
# 
 # Adjust key height and width
 g3 = g3 + theme(
   legend.key.height = unit(.3, "cm"),
   legend.key.width = unit(0.5, "cm"))

 # Get the ggplot Grob
 gt3 = ggplotGrob(g3)

 # grid.ls(grid.force(gt))  # To get a list of editable grobs

 # Edit the relevant keys
 library(grid)
 gt3 <- editGrob(grid.force(gt3), gPath("key-[3,4]-1-[1,2]"), 
                 grep = TRUE, global = TRUE,
                 x0 = unit(0, "npc"), y0 = unit(0.5, "npc"), 
                 x1 = unit(1, "npc"), y1 = unit(0.5, "npc")) 

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(gt1, gt2, gt3, widths=c(0.3,0.3,0.3), ncol=3)

# export plot as a .tex file in the tikz format
dev.off() # export file and exit tikzDevice function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, just use: `xlab("$\\gamma_{0}$")`